# Ubuntu 18.10 Missing GSync Option

Tags: nvidia

I just installed a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.10 and I've been trying to get g-sync to work but apparently, it's not even an option. It works fine in Windows 10 the monitor I have is a Dell S2716DG

[image: screen capture]

Thanks in advance.